# How to call to Doc2Vec from the cmd

Tags: deep-learning, word2vec

Does anyone knows of an implementation to paragraph vector algorithm or Doc2Vec that can be used from the cmd, without changing the source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gensim have ported Tomas Mikolov's word2vec and doc2vec original concepts to Python, which implements distributed memory and distributed bag of words models, using either hierarchical softmax or negative sampling. This will work with sentences, paragraphs and documents.

You can install from this location: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/install.html